# Is it decidable whether the iterates of a polynomial map are bounded?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, computability

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}^n\to \mathbb{Q}^n$ be a polynomial map with rational coefficients. Let $p\in \mathbb{Q}^n$. Is there a known algorithm that  given this data determines whether or not the iterates $f(p), f(f(p)),\ldots$ are bounded? Is this problem known to be algorithmically undecidable?